# .NET how to process excel (.xlsx) file to list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, excel, maui, maui-community-toolkit

do you know how to process excel files and "transform" them into List ?
Using .NET

I'm using this file picker https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-picker?tabs=windows

And now I don't know how to continue

Should I just read the content somehow split it by rows or cells and try to map it

Comment: You may consider using [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK) NuGet package to read the data. When using _DocumentFormat.OpenXml_ you'll find using the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5) to be helpful. However, the Productivity Tool hasn't been updated for newer versions of the OpenXml package, so you may consider using version 2.19 of the _DocumentFormat.OpenXml_ package. Also see [DocumentFormat.OpenXml Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml?view=openxml-2.7.2).

Comment: One thing I've used in the past is ExcelDataReader. It reads in the sense of row["column"] and you can build objects from enumerating the rows. It works in .NET Framework/Core/5+